# How NOT to change camera position on viewport size change?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: on normal viewport size]

The above image shows the minimap camera position I want to remain at. At all time. however when I tried to change its viewport size,(like the image below) the minimap camera position moves along the viewport size change causing the camera to show off-map parts. so how can I make my camera position stays wherever it is regardless of the viewport size?

[image]

ps: I said that the camera changed position but when I checked in the inspector the position value isnt really changing either so im not sure what to call it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's not very clear how can we help without seeing the code, however I'm sure the code might be fairly large

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov I didn't write any code for the minimap I tried using render textures, and the game overall doesn't really have that many code either

Comment: check your minimap in the hierarchy. Scale (and all transform changes) take place along all the game objects hierarchy. Check that when you change the veiwport size you are not changing the scale of any game object that might be in the changed gameobject's hierarchy that you do not want to be changed

Comment: @rustyBucketBay im sorry, i have rechecked the hierarchy and it seems my camera was a child of a certain game object i have unparented it now and it worked perfectly! sorry to waste your time

Comment: glad to help :)